# GitHub : Personal Access Token in remote URL property produces additional warning at push if I own the repository

Tags: git, github

I have cloned 2 repositories with the command `git clone https://{my_token}@{host}/{owner}/{repository}`

Therefore when running `git remote -v` for both, my token is part of the URL property

The first repository is under an organisation I am a member of (so owner = "some_organisation")
The second is a repository I own (so owner = "my_login")

For reference, the host is a GitHub Enterprise website

When I push "quietly" to these repositories with `git push -u -q origin {branch_name}`, for the first repository's working copy there is no output or error (as expected), but for the second there is a warning of the form

```
This repository moved. Please use the new location :
https://{host}/my_login/{repository}
```

As if the presence of my token in the URL property was causing some discrepancy.

This difference still holds if I change the visibility of both repositories (Public, Private, Internal...)

I have read ways to fix this (basically run `git remote set-url origin https://{host}/my_login/{repository}`), but I can't find an explanation as to why there is a difference in behavior between the 2.

**My question is : why is there a difference in behavior ? And can I circumvent that (i.e. have my token in my URL for a self-owned repository AND not have this warning when pushing)**

I'm also asking because, in my application, the users can create repositories to share their data- with, and currently I have not restrained them from using self-owned repositories. When performing a push, I check the standard error of the process, and it outputs this warning when the repository is self-owned

I tried :

- changing my git credentials settings
- regenerating a personal access token
- changing the visibility of the test repositories